# Rails 3: Recaptcha name error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, recaptcha

I am getting this error when pressing submit on my form with reCaptcha:

```
NameError in PostsController#create

undefined local variable or method `verify_captcha' for #<PostsController:0x007fcf52e84b48>
```

I have the gem installed with the registered private and public keys from the recaptcha website and the keys in the config file. I have ran 'bundle install'. The captcha works on the form as I am able to refresh new codes.

```
#gemfile
 gem "recaptcha", :require => "recaptcha/rails"

#controller
    respond_to do |format|
          if verify_captcha and @post.save
            format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }

          else
            format.html { render action: "new" }         
          end
        end
```

Why isn't rails recognizing the 'verify_captcha' method from the Recaptcha gem library? Any one know a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the method is called `verify_recaptcha`, not `verify_captcha`.